# Null pointer exception when setting title of toolbar widget

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-toolbar

I'm trying to set a title for my toolbar widget, but after doing so the last line of my code becomes highlighted in yellow and I get a null pointer exception warning. What can be done to solve this issue?

> Method invocation 'getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("" + getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world) + ""));' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

```
   Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
   getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>" + getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world) + "</font>"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The null pointer exception is only going to be thrown if the action bar would not be set. In your case it was merely a warning, there should be no error. However if you want to get rid of your warning try wrapping it with 'if' statement:

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>" + getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world) + "</font>"));
}
```

Comment: It will not solve the problem as the code will return "null" and logic cannot get inside !=null, which is obvious.

Comment: As the toolbar is set one line prior, the code cannot return null, unless somehow the constructor would return null, which is impossible. The if merely hides the warning.